# unable to connect to the aws ec2 ubuntu instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Getting error

failed to connect to your instance,

Previously it was running perfectly,

Could you please tell me, why is it not connecting?

my instance is running, occurring this error

failed to connect to your instance, error establishing ssh connection to your instance ec2

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use public and private i-e ppk,pem keys to connect the instance.

Comment: Thanks, once i have restarted the instance, connected successfully

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to post screenshots of error that you are facing? It will give more clear idea. Few suggestions -

If in Security group, for port 22 you have used My ip, try removing it & again give my ip. As home router restarts, new ip is assigned to it.

Check if correct key is used ie pem or ppk

Comment: Thanks, once i have restarted the instance, connected successfully